# Askubuntu.com Profile doesn't accept Unicode Character as name

Tags: feature-request, bug

I am from Myanmar and I try to update my Display Name in Myanmar language but it doesn't accept the Unicode character and it only accepts English characters. How to solve it?

[image: Doesn't Accept Unicode Input in Display Name]

Comment: Can you edit to include the text of your desired display name, maybe the method of display is the culprit, or it may be likely one of the letters is not coming up as a letter it is possible to put these into your name Just tried one on mine http://askubuntu.com/users/47291/mat%e1%80%a1

Comment: Even though if you put the unicode character, the website should show the name, it means there is something wrong with their input string data acceptance :)

Comment: Can you paste it in this question?

Comment: @YhalHtetAung that depends a bit... can you please paste the desired name here in the question? Whether the validation is appropriate or not depends on: what **exactly** is the text that isn't working? We do *not* restrict to English characters, but there are some restrictions.

Comment: ရဲထက်အောင်  is the name. :)

Comment: some of those symbols are ok on their own, but there are some strange combinations symbols in there, sepcifically this one: အော

Comment: actully it's just this letter causing the problem: ေ it combines and switches places with other letters (which is probably why it is on the blacklist), may I suggest using something that looks similar say a 6 then you can use  - ရဲထက်6အင်

Comment: hm, that is still missing that little bit

Comment: this might look similar enough ↄ

Comment: Which DBMS you guys are using? :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Pinging in case you didn't get the reply.

Comment: @Seth ah, yes - this is the first time I've seen a notification - will check tomorrow

Comment: @Yhal the DBMS is unicode aware; the rule violation is in app-code

Comment: it seems to be excluding the charters that combine on the right and left, it is extremely hard to separate those characters, do you mind making a list of them all with commas or spaces in-between to prevent combination.

Comment: If you use MySQL and PostgreSQL (for e.g.) it accepts the Unicode and there is no problem for input. That is why I am wondering which DBMS askubuntu is using :) And I think it is in app-code so no choice :D

Answer (score 3):

The issue is two spacing-combining characters (ော) at index 6 that don't pass our validation. I'm investigating what the best option is there.

Comment: Is this related to [Can’t change username to an all-alphabetic word](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231843)?